# How to resolve undefined offset notice? It always show

Tags: php, error-handling

I have some problem when i used PHP operators to compare 2 of array value. And notice error like this : `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\` always show on my browser. All the way i have done to fix it. But it show the same results when i execution it. Can anybody help me to fix it?

```
$perbandingan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ar_produk_detail WHERE id_produk = '$_GET[id]'");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($perbandingan);
    while($w = mysql_fetch_array($perbandingan)){
        $w_id[] = $w['id_subkategori'];
        $p_id[] = $w['id_produk_det'];
        $d_id[] = $w['id_produk'];
    }

    $data = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $sum = count($data);

for($t = 0; $t < $rows; $t++){
    if($w_id[$t] == $data[$t]){ //Notices error always reference by this line
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM ar_produk_detail WHERE id_produk_det = '$p_id[t]'");
}
```

Comment: You should really read up on sql injection and PDO / mysqli and prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You could just check to make sure the offsets exist in your conditional:

```
if(isset($w_id[$t]) && isset($data[$t]) && $w_id[$t] == $data[$t])
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer so halpfull there is no error anymore.. but why the data on mysql_query not execute correctly?

Comment: because you left the variable sign out. should be this - $p_id[$t]